# Can anyone confirm that IBM Cloud works from China?

Tags: ibm-cloud, great-firewall-of-china

I am a Unity game/simulation developer who works at a non-profit lab at a university in Indiana, USA. We have recently entered an art/tech exhibition in Beijing, China.

The theme of the exhibition is AI. Our proposal was accepted and includes the use of several IBM Cloud services (Speech To Text, Language Translator, and Tone Analyzer). We have had internet-related issues at exhibitions in Beijing before and I have been unable to confirm whether IBM Cloud services are accessible from China.

I know there is a server hub in Tokyo. Can anyone confirm that IBM Cloud (and specifically the aforementioned services) is available from Beijing?

I could not find any information on the IBM Cloud website confirming the accessibility from China. Their "Support" > "Ask the community" links led me to StackOverflow.

Comment: David, I am an Alibaba MVP Network Security. When you design services that involve China, you need to build everything as either only in China or only the rest of the world. Do not plan on crossing the border with data. The licenses that are available are for external companies to host sites in China using data centers in China and not for cross border data transfer. There are workarounds but they are only temporary. Once discovered the government shuts down your connections. I am not aware of any "VPN Licenses" to accomplish your goal except for Corporate home links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David, the Watson services are not available in China.

We are working on adding them to South Korea but there is no eta at this time.

Comment: Thank you, German. If we were to obtain a license to use a government-sanctioned VPN, would we be able to access Watson from China?

Comment: I don't know who that works @DavidRodriguez. Why don't you join this Watson slack https://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/ and ask Mitch Mason. He may be able to help

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, for a list of services and current hosting locations see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/resources?topic=resources-services_region